# Error writing binary file in Python

Tags: python, file, binaryfiles

I have a Python program that receives a binary file via parameter and writes this file in a directory. But when it writes the file, some characters the program replaces it with a series of numbers. Below the original file the program receives as a parameter:

```
**ÐT_Ö/¤Ðæ¨®kMµûÀz”Ô(Î,“+œd¼Es¥**
```

But when the program writes, look at the result:

```
**ÐT_Ö/¤Ðæ¨®kMµûÀz &#148 ; Ô(Î, &#147 ; &#156 ;d¼Es¥**
```

You can see that the character **”** between characters **z** and **Ô** was replaced by sequence **&#148 ;**. Also the caracter "+" between characters **Î,** and **œd** was replaced by sequence **&#147**

Below the Python program code that do the leitiura and recording binary file

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
def chamaProg(arquivo): 
   var_file = open("C:\\Nitgen\\arquivo.rec","wb")
   conteudo_texto = var_file.write(arquivo)
   var_file.close()
```

Why is it happening? What should I do to read and write all the characters correctly?

Comment: This is not Python's fault.

Comment: How are you viewing the results?

Comment: The unicode characters [&#148](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/148) and [&#147](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/147).

Comment: I am viewing the result via a Hex Editor Program:

Comment: Make sure that `arquivo` is a `bytes` object in Python 3 or a `str` in Python 2. Otherwise the original string might be interpreted as regular text and converted to different charsets.

Comment: Most likely this is resulting from some sort of HTML or XML parsing which you are doing.  Without more details on that part of your program, we cannot help you.